# object is currently use elsewhere while rotate picturebox

Tags: c#, exception, rotation, picturebox, unhandled

I have three images each one in a picturebox and when threads starts they begin to rotate

```
threads[0] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Display1));
        place(ref threads[0], comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
        threads[0].Start();
```

then in display1 function i use below code to rotate

```
   protected void Display1()
    {
        for (long i = 0L; i < 200000; i++)
        {


            {
                Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
                img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }

    }
```

but it just gets unhandled exception "Object is currently use elsewhere" i try to use lock and picturebox1.invalidate but i has no use.

Comment: You can't go randomly updating UI controls from a non-UI thread.

Comment: I have define a Rotating class which has a function that gets the image and rotate it and then return it and i add below codes too:      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {                
                
                {
                    Image img;
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { img = pictureBox2.Image; });
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pictureBox2.Image = Rotating.Rotate(img); });
                }
            } and i still have the erro